# JSViews two way binding update inner array when top level variable changes

Tags: jsrender, jsviews

I am trying to convert this knockout code to JSViews: [here](https://codepen.io/cmegown/pen/VaMzQq)

I can make it work for the first iteration, but clicking on a color does not update the array and therefore does not add the 'js-active' class. I know the reason is because I am not observing for that change, but I cant seem to see how to connect the two.

I have taken the two separate ko.observbles and joined them in to one:

```
var colorPickerData = {
selectedColor: "Red",

materialColors: [
    {
        color: "Red",
        variations: [
            {
                weight: 50,
                hex: "#FFEBEE"
....
```

and here is the template:

```
 <script id="color-picker-template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="material-color-picker">
        <div class="material-color-picker__left-panel">
            <ol class="color-selector"> 
                {^{for materialColors ~paletteColor=selectedColor }}
                <li>
                    <input name="material-color" type="radio" data-link="id{:'materialColor' + #getIndex() } checked{:~paletteColor} value{:color}">
                    <label data-link="for{:'materialColor' + #getIndex()} title{:color} css-color{:variations[4].hex }"></label>
                </li>
                {{/for}}
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="material-color-picker__right-panel">
           {^{for materialColors ~paletteColor=selectedColor}}
            <div data-link="class{:(color == ~paletteColor)? 'js-active color-palette-wrapper': 'color-palette-wrapper' }">

                <h5 class="color-palette-header" data-link="text{:color}"></h5>
                <ol class="color-palette">
                    {^{for variations}}
                    <li id="clipboardItem" class="color-palette__item" data-link="data-clipboard-text{:hex } css-background-color{:hex }">
                        <span data-link="text{:weight}"></span>
                        <span data-link="text{:hex}"></span>

                    </li>
                    {{/for}}
                </ol>

            </div>
            {{/for}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the linking code:

```
$.templates("#color-picker-template").link("#color-wrapper", colorPickerData, true);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can observe for the changes to selectedColor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/borismoore/details/awxwov/) and completed a port to JsViews.

I simplified some of the data-linking markup to reduce perf cost of unnecessary data binding.

For your question about two-way binding to radio buttons:

You can do

```
{^{radiogroup selectedColor}}
  {{for materialColors}}
    <li>
        <input name="material-color" id="materialColor{{:#index}}" value="{{:color}}" type="radio" />
        <label ...></label>
    </li>
  {{/for}}
{{/radiogroup}}
```

or

```
{{for materialColors ~paletteColor=selectedColor}}
  <li>
    <input name="material-color" id="materialColor{{:#index}}" value="{{:color}}" type="radio" data-link="~paletteColor"/>
    <label ...></label>
  </li>
{{/for}}
```

or - if you keep your full data-linking approach:

```
<input name="material-color" type="radio" data-link="id{:'materialColor' + #getIndex() } value{:color} {:~paletteColor:}">
```

See [{{radiogroup}}](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvradiogrouptag) and [Data-linked radio buttons](http://www.jsviews.com/#link-input@radio).

Comment: thank you so much for this. Your work is fantastic and really appreciated.

Comment: I liked your color picker sample. I might include the JsViews version as a custom tag control sample (with some additions and improvements) on jsviews.com, it that was OK with you. BTW could you maybe mark the answer above as 'accepted'?